pip3 upgrading Python dependencies - SSL error (unsafe legacy renegotiation failed)
I'm trying to update some Python dependencies (mainly the remotior-sensus) using OSGeo4W, installed with QGIS 3.34.9. This is using Python 3.12.4.
I'm following instructions on this site: https://semiautomaticclassificationmanual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_win64.html#qgis-download-and-installation and have managed to download the dependencies, but cannot install them.
Using
pip3 install --upgrade remotior-sensus scikit-learn torch

I get the following:
Requirement already satisfied: remotior-sensus in c:\progra~1\qgis33~1.9\apps\python312\lib\site-packages (0.3.5)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/remotior-sensus/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/remotior-sensus/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/remotior-sensus/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/remotior-sensus/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/remotior-sensus/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/remotior-sensus/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/remotior-sensus/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))) - skipping
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/scikit-learn/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/scikit-learn/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/scikit-learn/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/scikit-learn/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))': /simple/scikit-learn/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/scikit-learn/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-learn (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scikit-learn
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled (_ssl.c:1000)'))) - skipping

Does anyone have any ideas? Just really need this installed so I can use the Semi Automatic Classification Plugin.

Maybe a solution here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

@GBG that definitely had part of the solution, will detail in answer.

So, I followed the top answer from @GBG and created a custom OPENSSL.CNF file, as below:
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation

I then told OSGeo4W to use this file:

set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\temp\AFile\openssl.cnf

And checked using the following:

echo %openssl_conf%

Updated Pip, using:

pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pytest-xdist
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip

This seemed to get everything ready for my main line:

pip3 install --upgrade remotior-sensus scikit-learn torch

Which finally worked!
